# Show two objects in one AJAX datatable column

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using jQuery datatables to output data via Ajax and SQL. I can output the data fine. However, I would like to combine two of the return objects into one column as it pertains to the same thing.

```
$('#todayApt').on('show.bs.modal', function (event){
    $('#todayAptList').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": '{{ url('panel/appointment/ajax/schedule/week/lookup') }}',
            dataSrc: ''
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "date" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "block" },
            { "data": "last_name" },
            { "data": "street_1" },
            { "data": "zip_code" },
            { "data": "phone_1" },
            { "data": "service_detail" }
        ]
    } );
});
```

My object is as follows:

```
[  
   {  
      "street_1":"1234 Main St",
      "phone_2":"(555) 555-5555",
      "street_2":null,
      "date":"2016-10-19",
      "users_info_id":19,
      "last_name":"Doe",
      "phone_1":"(555) 555-5555",
      "zip_code":90210,
      "status":"scheduled",
      "office":"location",
      "block":"9-12",
      "special_detail":null,
      "mp_detail":null,
      "service_detail":"Service Details"
   }
]
```

So service_detail, mp_detail and special_detail I would like to just be in one single column labeled 'Details'. I can figure out how to do single columns but cannot figure out how to do more than one in only one column

Example of expected results:

```
<table id="todayAptList" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Block</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Services</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">2016-10-18</td>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>3-5</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>1234 Main St</td>
      <td>90210</td>
      <td>(555) 555-5555</td>
      <td>SPECIAL, MP AND SERVICE DETAILS HERE IN ONE</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is the returne result a JSON object?

Comment: Yes it is. I'll edit my answer to show the proper JSON response that was a dump from my SQL object.

Comment: Could you provide the result you expect?

Comment: why not just combine the 2 index inside your php script

Comment: @Anson I edited the post to reflect my desired results.

Comment: @NewbeeDev I could if I had to. In this situation those three details are being grouped together in a complex manner already. I am trying to not further complicate the backend if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the renderer (columns.render). See here for reference:
[DataTable Renderers](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers)

Basically you use the renderer to transform data from the original object.  You could do something like this in the column that you'd like the combined info (untested, but I just modified some code I used to do the exact same thing earlier today):

```
$('#todayApt').on('show.bs.modal', function (event){
$('#todayAptList').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": '{{ url('panel/appointment/ajax/schedule/week/lookup') }}',
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "date" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "block" },
        { "data": "last_name" },
        { "data": "street_1" },
        { "data": "zip_code" },
        { "data": "phone_1" },
        { 
            "data": null, 
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var details = row.service_detail + " " + row.mp_detail + " " + row.special_detail;
                        return details;
                    }
        }
    ]
});
```

I used the last column for this example.  The row parameter should contain the original json object.